# Some exercise on the regularity of a summability method

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, matrix-analysis, divergent-series, infinite-sequences

I was reading the book of Johann Boos "Classical and modern method in summability theory" and I came across an exercise from the Chapter 2 (page 50, exercise 2.3.15). Here is the statement of the exercise.

**Exercise** Let $A = (a_{m, n})_{m, n \geq 0}$ be an infinite matrix and let $\hat{A} := (a_{m, n} - a_{m, n + 1})_{m, n \geq 0}$. Show that the following assertions are equivalent:

1. If $\sum_{n \geq 0} x_n$ is a convergent series, then $A_m := \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{m, n} x_n$ is convergent for every $m \geq 0$ and $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} A_m$ exists.
2. The matrix $A$ satisfies the following conditions:

   - For all $m \geq 0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{mn} = 0$.
   - $\sup_{m \geq 0} \sum_{n \geq 0} |a_{m,n} - a_{m, n+1}| < \infty$.
   - $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = 0} (a_{m, n} - a_{m, n+1})$ exists.
   - $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} (a_{m, n} - a_{m, n + 1} )$ exists for every $m \geq 0$.

To avoid defining too much terminology from the book, I write down the exercise in a different way. More precisely, I omitted to state the third equivalent condition: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{mn} = 0$ and $\hat{A}$ is a conservative matrix summability method. It doesn't affect the point I make however. The goal of this exercise was to characterize the infinite matrices which are called conservative for convergent series (this is exactly the condition 1 above).

Here's the thing... I think that I found a counterexample which satisfies the condition 1., but not the condition $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} a_{m, n} = 0$ for every $m \geq 0$ in the second condition 2. My counterexample is the matrix $A$ with all its entries being 1, that is
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{pmatrix} .$$
All the $A_m$ are then $\sum_{n \geq 0} x_n$ which is convergent and $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} A_m$ exists since it is a constant sequence, however $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} a_{mn} = 1$ for every $m \geq 0$!

To solve this exercise, Boos suggests to use Abel's summation by parts formula, that is
$$ \sum_{n = j}^{j + k} x_n y_n = \sum_{n = j}^{j + k} s_n (y_n - y_{n + 1}) - s_{j - 1} y_j + s_{j + k} y_{j + k + 1} $$
where $s_n$ are the partial sums of the series $\sum_{k \geq 0} x_k$. If we put $y_n = a_{m, n}$ and $j = 0$, then we get
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{k} x_n a_{m, n} = \sum_{n = 0}^{k} s_n (a_{m, n} - a_{m, n + 1}) + s_{k} a_{m, k + 1}.$$
From this last expression, I can see why we have the other conditions and, maybe, why we must have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{mn} = 0$ for every $m \geq 0$.

Did I miss something? My counterexample seems legit to me, but maybe I don't see something.

Thank you for your help!
(Sorry if there are any English typos...)

Comment: Some further comments on the question.

I think that the condition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{m, n} = 0$ is sufficient but not necessary. The examples I have in mind are the Cesàro summation methods, which are defined in the following way : 
$$ \sigma_m^\alpha = \frac{1}{\binom{n+ \alpha}{\alpha}} \sum_{n = 0}^m \binom{m - n + \alpha}{\alpha} x_n$$
where $\binom{n + \alpha}{\alpha}$ is a binomial coefficient and $\alpha > -1$. The coefficients of the method clearly have the property mentioned since the infinite matrix associated to it is lower triangular.